# How to make the bot's status a variable

Tags: javascript, discord.js

here's my code:

```
//All of the constants
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./myconfig10.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const request = require('request');
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));




//Telling the bot where to look for the commands
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

let activities = [
    'with ur dad',
    'with ur mom',
]

const pickedActivity = Math.floor(Math.random() * (activities.length - 1) + 1)

//Once the bot is up and running, display 'Ready' in the console
client.once('ready', () => {
    client.user.setPresence({
        status: 'online',
        activity: {
            name: (pickedActivity),
            type: 'STREAMING',
            url: 'https://www.twitch.tv/monstercat'
        }
    })
    console.log('Ready!');
    


//Seeing if the message starts with the prefix
client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

//Telling the bot what arguments are
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/)
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

//Checking to see if the command you sent is one of the commands in the commands folder 
    if (!client.commands.has(commandName)) return;
    console.log(`Collected 1 Item, ${message}`)

    const command = client.commands.get(commandName);

//Try to execute the command.
    try {
        command.execute(message, args);
    
//If there's an error, don't crash the bot. 
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        
//Sends a message on discord telling you there was an error
        message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');




    
    }})})

client.login(token);
```

but when i try this, i get the error:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied name is not a string.

I know this means that the name of the status needs to be a string, so how would I be able to make it a variable?

I'm pretty new to this so it would be appreciated if your answer was in simple enough terms.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you meant to do `name: activities[pickedActivity]`? ("with ur mom" instead of `1`?)

Comment: @blex yes! thank you, I'm really new to arrays and how they work so I didn't catch that

Comment: Array indexes start at `0`, but you always add `+ 1` to `pickedActivity`, so it can never be "with ur dad". Try this: `const pickedActivity = Math.floor(Math.random() * activities.length);`

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick. Replace:

```js
const pickedActivity = Math.floor(Math.random() * (activities.length - 1) + 1)
```

with:

```js
const pickedActivity = activities[Math.floor(Math.random() * activities.length)]
```